# Proving an integral using a series

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis

If $f:(0,1]\rightarrow \textbf {R}$ is defined by $f(x)=2nx$ for $\frac{1}{n+1}\leq x \leq \frac 1n$ and $n$ is a natural number, assuming that $\sum_{k=1}^{k=\infty}1/k^2=\pi^2/6$,  show that $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=\pi^2/6$.

So I wrote the summation of the integral from $x=\frac{1}{n+1}$ to $x=\frac{1}{n}$ of $f(x)dx$. After I integrate I'm left with the infinite series of $\frac{1}{k}-\frac{k}{(k+1)^2}$ from $k=1$ to $k=\infty$? Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Ok, so I can do this. But the way I can do this is way more nontrivial than I was thinking it would be, so I wanted to check: how difficult should this be? Is this a challenging problem in a challenging class? Or is this supposed to be a totally reasonable problem?

Comment: I don't think this was supposed to be this challenging.I have tried to manipulate the last sum so I can use the fact that the sum of 1/k^2=(pi)^2/6

Comment: If I manipulate the last sum to ((2k^2+k)/((k+1)^2)*(1/k^2). Then couldn't I just say that the limit of the first is 1 and by hypothesis the sum of 1/k^2=(pi)^2/6?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple way:

$$\begin{align}\int_0^1 dx \, f(x) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2 n \int_{1/(n+1)}^{1/n} dx\; x\\ &=  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \left [\frac1{n^2} - \frac1{(n+1)^2} \right ]\\ &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \left (\frac1{n}-\frac1{n+1}\right )\left (\frac1{n}+\frac1{n+1}\right )\\ &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n+1}\left (\frac1{n}+\frac1{n+1}\right )\\ &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left (\frac1{n(n+1)} + \frac1{(n+1)^2} \right )  \\ &= 1 + \frac{\pi^2}{6}-1 \\ &= \frac{\pi^2}{6}\end{align}$$

Comment: Ohh, and it factors. I didn't think of that. Just to let you know, the first way I did it was very direct: summing $\frac{1}{n(n+1)^2}$ to get $2 - \zeta(2)$, which I happen to know only because I used it in a math contest problem solution recently.

Comment: @mixedmath: That's pretty slick.  What math contest?

Comment: It's actually in the American Mathematical Monthly (that's a contest of sorts, right?). I don't know if you ever look at those, but every now and then they have really nice problems.

Comment: @mixedmath: good enough for me.  I'm going to have to add that to my reading pile/hill/mountain.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

I feel a bit silly, as I missed the clearly correct way to do this.

As you say, you manipulate the integral into the sum

$$ \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{1}{k} - \frac{k}{(k+1)^2}.$$

We now use the deep fact that $k = k + 1 - 1$ to finish.

$$ \begin{align}
\sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{1}{k} - \frac{k}{(k+1)^2} &= \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{1}{k} - \frac{k+1}{(k+1)^2} + \frac{1}{(k+1)^2} \\
&= \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1} + \frac{1}{(k+1)^2} \\
&= \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}.
\end{align}$$